# Problem with starting elementary OS

Tags: system-installation, settings, install

I have installed elementary OS alongside Win 10 and when I try to open elementary OS I get error message "usci_acpi UBSC0000:00: PPM init failed (-110)" I don't know how I could fix it and I can't really find any help on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is the same as [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1850238). hope it helps.

Comment: I think it doesn't adress my issue